# Installing helm chart under custom namespace

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, microk8s

I am trying to install some helm charts into custom namespaces on a Microk8s cluster but get the following errors. What am I doing wrong? The cluster is fresh and none of these namespaces or resources exist.

```sh
> helm install loki grafana/loki-stack -f values/loki-stack.yaml --namespace loki --create-namespace
W0902 08:08:35.878632 1610435 warnings.go:70] policy/v1beta1 PodSecurityPolicy is deprecated in v1.21+, unavailable in v1.25+
Error: rendered manifests contain a resource that already exists. Unable to continue with install: 
PodSecurityPolicy "loki-grafana" in namespace "" exists and cannot be imported into the current release: 
invalid ownership metadata; annotation validation error: 
key "meta.helm.sh/release-namespace" must equal "loki": current value is "default"

> helm install traefik traefik/traefik -f values/traefik.yml --namespace traefik --create-namespace
Error: rendered manifests contain a resource that already exists. Unable to continue with install: 
ClusterRole "traefik" in namespace "" exists and cannot be imported into the current release: 
invalid ownership metadata; annotation validation error: 
key "meta.helm.sh/release-namespace" must equal "traefik": current value is "default"
```

Comment: Hello @Johan Book Is there are any releases for loki and traefik in Helm already? Can you check them with 'helm list -A' command?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. When I run `helm list -A` it reports no releases.

Answer (score 1):

The resource (**loki**) to be deployed already exists in the specified namespace.

Please check with `helm list -n loki`.

So before you install it, you need to uninstall it first.

1. `helm uninstall loki -n loki`
2. `helm install loki grafana/loki-stack -f values/loki-stack.yaml --namespace loki`

Or you can try to update it directly:

`helm upgrade loki grafana/loki-stack -f values/loki-stack.yaml --namespace loki`

Comment: I checked `helm list -n loki`, there are no resources there. I tried uninstalling it but it fails as it was not installed